# Google Colab Execution Bug

Tags: python, google-chrome, debugging, google-colaboratory, execution

I've been using google colab to code in python for 2 months and everything was going well until last night. When I execute a code in python, which worked very well the previous days, it works during the first execution then when I launch it a second time it marks: execution...then after 10 seconds I have a message that appears:

"Auto save failed. This file has been modified remotely or in another tab".
But I've got Internet.

What can I do?

Thanks a lot

I've tried changing the execution environment but the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cookies or running code in another browser

Comment: I tried and It doesn't change anything...any other idea ?

Comment: Maybe the problem is with your account. Try running code from another one

Comment: I have noticed that when I run a code where there is any torch function it works well. Is it possible that is because of Torch ?

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: Yes, actually I'v noticed that when I try to run one cell it works but when I try to run the next cell (not simultaneously ) the execution run and then I have the message ""Auto save failed. This file has been modified remotely or in another tab". But I'am connected to Internet.